# Bingo Cards PDF

Tags: code-golf, card-games, file-system

Write code to generate a PDF file containing 6 bingo cards. Winner is the one that uses the shortest code and needs no actions except for installing a library and running the code. (No Save As PDF). Rules are as follows.

- The generated PDF file should display accurately in Adobe's PDF reader, Google Chrome and Moxilla Firefox.
- Page size should be either Letter or A4.
- Cards should be arranged in 3 rows and 2 columns.
- Each card should be 3 inches in width and height.
- Each card should contain numbers 1 to 25 in random order, arranged in 5x5 squares. The numbers in all 6 cards should be generated independently.
- Text size should be 20 points.
- Text font should be Helvetica, Arial, Calibri or Open Sans. Text should be centered in each cell.
- The bingo cards should have borders with lines having thickness either 0.5 or 1 points.
- You can use a pre-existing, publicly available library or package to create a PDF file but the code to generate and arrange bingo cards should be your own.
- These is a margin of 20% allowed in each dimension, but all cards should be strictly equal in size.

## Reference Answer

Install `reportlab` using `pip install reportlab`

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from random import shuffle
my_canvas = canvas.Canvas("Bingo Cards.pdf", pagesize=letter)
my_canvas.setLineWidth(1)
my_canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 20)
a = [i for i in range(1, 26)]
for row in range(0, 3):
    for col in range (0, 2):
        shuffle(a)
        rowplace = 252*row
        colplace = 276*col
        my_canvas.line(60+colplace, 36+rowplace, 276+colplace, 36+rowplace)
        my_canvas.line(276+colplace, 36+rowplace, 276+colplace, 246+rowplace)
        my_canvas.line(60+colplace, 36+rowplace, 60+colplace, 246+rowplace)
        my_canvas.line(60+colplace, 246+rowplace, 276+colplace, 246+rowplace)
        for grid in range(0, 5):
            gridplace = grid*43.2
            my_canvas.line(60+colplace, 36+rowplace+gridplace, 276+colplace, 36+rowplace+gridplace)
            my_canvas.line(60+colplace+gridplace, 36+rowplace, 60+colplace+gridplace, 246+rowplace)
            for i in range(0, 5):
                my_canvas.drawCentredString(81.6+colplace+gridplace, 47.6+rowplace+i*43.2, str(a[i+5*grid]))
my_canvas.save()
```

The result is shown in the following image.

[image: Sample bingo cards PDF]

Comment: Is this a [tag:code-golf] challenge? As the post is currently phrased, it lacks objective winning criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @noodleman. I added the winning criteria.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 380 bytes

Requires `reportlab`.
Install `reportlab` using `pip install reportlab`.

Default A4 pagesize, the margin on the dimensions allows for the rounding on the cards' positions.

Save the pdf file as "b".

```python
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import random
b=canvas.Canvas('b')
b.setLineWidth(1)
b.setFont('Helvetica',20)
n=list(range(25))
w=216
d=43
for y in(48,313,577):
 for x in(54,325):
  random.shuffle(n);b.lines([(x,y,x+w,y),(x,y,x,y+w)])
  for i in range(25):f,g=x+d*(i%5),y+d*(i//5);b.lines([(x,g+d,x+w,g+d),(f+d,y,f+d,y+w)]);b.drawCentredString(f+22,g+12,str(n[i]+1))
b.save()
```

---

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), fully parametrized, 551 bytes

Default A4 pagesize.
All the dimensions are parametrized:

- font size
- numbers in each card
- number of cards in the page, arranged in rows and columns
- size of card

Save the pdf file as "b".

```python
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
import random
b=canvas.Canvas('b')
b.setLineWidth(1)
t=20
b.setFont('Helvetica',t)
k=25
q=int(k**.5)
n=list(range(k))
r=3
c=2
w=3*inch
h=3*inch
d=w/q
e=h/q
o=(b._pagesize[0]-w*c)/(c+1)
v=(b._pagesize[1]-h*r)/(r+1)
for y in range(r):
 y=y*(v+h)+v
 for x in range(c):
  x=x*(o+w)+o;random.shuffle(n);b.lines([(x,y,x+w,y),(x,y,x,y+h)])
  for i in range(k):f,g=x+d*(i%q),y+e*(i//q);b.lines([(x,g+e,x+w,g+e),(f+d,y,f+d,y+h)]);b.drawCentredString(f+d/2,g+(e-t)/2,str(n[i]+1))
b.save()
```

---

*Code with comments*

```python
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
import random

# pdf canvas, default A4
b=canvas.Canvas('b')
b.setLineWidth(1)

t=20
b.setFont('Helvetica',t)

# numbers in each card
k=25
# numbers in cards are arranged in perfect squares
q=int(k**.5)
n=list(range(k))

# cards in page, arranged in rows and columns
r=3
c=2

# width and height of cards
w=3*inch
h=3*inch

# size of cells
d=w/q
e=h/q

# spacing between cards
o=(b._pagesize[0]-w*c)/(c+1)
v=(b._pagesize[1]-h*r)/(r+1)

# loop on rows in page
for y in range(r):

    # bottom position of card
    y=y*(v+h)+v

    # loop on columns in page
    for x in range(c):

        # left position of card
        x=x*(o+w)+o

        # randomize numbers
        random.shuffle(n)

        # draw the bottom and left line of card
        b.lines([(x,y,x+w,y),(x,y,x,y+h)])

        # loop on numbers
        for i in range(k):

            # orizontal and vertical position of the lines
            # as offset from the initial position of the card
            f,g=x+d*(i%q),y+e*(i//q)

            # draw lines
            b.lines([(x,g+e,x+w,g+e),(f+d,y,f+d,y+h)])

            # draw number as text, centered in the cell
            b.drawCentredString(f+d/2,g+(e-t)/2,str(n[i]+1))

# save pdf canvas as file
b.save()
```