# Bingo Cards SVG Code

Tags: code-golf, random

Generate the contents of an SVG file containing 6 bingo cards. Winner is the one that uses the shortest code. A qualifying answer has an output that can be directly pasted in a blank to get the required image. Rules are as follows.

- The generated SVG code should comply with SVG version 1.1 described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/).
- The size of the image should be equal to either Letter or A4 page sizes.
- Cards should be arranged in 3 rows and 2 columns.
- Each card should be 3 inches in width and height.
- Each card should contain numbers 1 to 25 in random order, arranged in 5x5 squares. The numbers in all 6 cards should be generated independently.
- Text size should be 20 points and text color should be black.
- Text font should be Helvetica, Arial, Calibri or Open Sans. Text should be centered in each cell.
- The line in the cards should have thickness either 0.5 or 1 points, and black color.
- The cards should be arranged evenly around the image: The vertical distances between cards and the vertical distances between the cards and image boundaries should all be the same. Similar for horizontal distances.
- There is a margin of 5% allowed in each dimension, but all cards should be strictly equal in size.

The following image shows the intended layout of the image, although sizes and spacing may not be accurate.

Can someone please close my [older question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266879/bingo-cards-pdf) and open up this one? This question is more realistic for because it doesn't need file-write operations or libraries. I could update the older question to remove the PDF requirement, but it was already getting allegations of a chameleon question so I didn't want to risk it. I can delete the older question if there is no other option but I would prefer to keep it (even if closed).

[image: sample bingo cards]

Answer (score -3):

## Python 3.10 <s>1954</s> 943 bytes

Thanks to the suggestion by lyxal, the code is almost half the original length.

```
from random import shuffle
def m(h,j,k,l):
    print('<line x1="'+str(h)+'pt" y1="'+str(j)+'pt" x2=\"'+str(k)+'pt" 
y2="'+str(l)+'pt" stroke="black" stroke-width="1pt" />')
print('<svg version="1.1" width="612pt" height="792pt" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">')
a=[i for i in range(1,26)]
for b in range(0,3):
    for c in range (0,2):
        shuffle(a)
        e=252*b
        d=276*c
        m(60+d,36+e,276+d,36+e)
        m(276+d,36+e,276+d,246+e)
        m(60+d,36+e,60+d,246+e)
        m(60+d,246+e,276+d,246+e)
        for g in range(0,5):
            f=g*43.2
            m(60+d,36+e+f,276+d,36+e+f)
            m(60+d+f,36+e,60+d+f,246+e)
            for i in range(0,5):
                print('<text x="'+str(81.6+d+f)+'pt" y="'+str(57.6+e+i*43.2)+'pt" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="20pt" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">'+str(a[i+5*g])+'</text>')
print("</svg>")
```

Comment: Hi there, even though this is a benchmark implementation, it still needs to be a "serious contender" - as defined [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8750/78850). In essence, variable names should be shortened where possible, extra whitespace should be removed, and any obvious golfing suggestions should be applied.

Comment: In addition to what @lyxal said: giving an ungolfed reference implementation is fine, but it should be included in the question, not as an answer.

Comment: @Arnauld, thanks for the suggestion. I will include this reference implementation in the question soon.

Comment: @lyxal thanks for the suggestion. Can you say if the rules of this site require a non-serious-contender answer to be removed?

Comment: Anyone downvoting this answer or voting for it to be deleted, it would be great if you can give some feedback on why this is an unsuitable answer. And please allow me a few days to check back and update it. I will include this answer in the original question once the question opens up again.

Comment: I would argue that this is a serious contender, as it clearly makes an effort to be golfed. That said, there are still a substantial number of byte savings that could be incorporated: I've linked a ~200 byte golf below.

Comment: [-266](https://tio.run/##ZZLNjtsgFIXX8VMgNvFf/EMaj5oJkbrrOyRZEBtsJja2gMZOo3n2FIij0agr7jkcffeiy3DTTS/WjweTfQckEZU5eDf0UofegAfJhfYqykDnN/FHfInbYDv4bLlruaBgyjG8N5@DhuBmyw9XTggf4f3i6qO4IXPROqG07C8Uw3NLystLrkZe6QbD3CbS/TLwBn@5U9caXKlUvBfmKskhmGNFjmywobxuNIZvP608iqlrhcKw0XrYpuk4jsm4TnpZpyjLstTQoCUTfAjNG2vq5zEqgpPHegnOgItDFhvntPUW1ilnx@qFav4w1lKfBEZQjDYoPEfr4r3C6K0Iy6jI3ju/immM8iIyZ2DkXM4WyrPI2db6Jl35LWV62AlqMwF4TroJ7BQLhuvwxzpBT0zEXu0i5lDGMGxnzxjH4f9xFm57mk4aTGYxKE8MJmLPHb4MGnHXzLnmR3BBhF6diaJ27Rh2vKpaCoHFrIgom15@maw3WcX/mhzKLMAZjHS8NQ1@SU7aGPym7ZVqXpIYKCLUSlHJGdzfyYFHm7A@fe5SC39@B7izG9zD4PH4Bw)